# Java MySQL web host recommendation

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, web-hosting

Not a programming question, but a question which is uniquely important to programmers.

Can anyone recommend a good Java Servlets/Mysql/Tomcat hosting provider.

Cost and ease of setup is the main consideration as this is just a demo.

Comment: By your own admission this isn't a programming question...

Comment: But it's still useful for programmers

Answer (score 1):

give amazon ec2 a try. its perfect and very cost effective for your requirement.